# Issue with PCL and CMake : StatisticalOutlierRemoval undefined while linking

Tags: c++, c++11, cmake, point-cloud-library

I am currently trying to filter a pointCloud using PCL thanks to StatisticalOutlierRemoval without using ROS, using only PCL I installed through the [official github repository](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary). I used [this](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/statistical_outlier.php) in my code and I get the following error while linking :

```
CMakeFiles/tests/11_pcl/removeOutliers.dir/removeOutliers.cpp.o: In function `pcl::StatisticalOutlierRemoval<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::applyFilter(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&)':
removeOutliers.cpp:(.text._ZN3pcl25StatisticalOutlierRemovalINS_11PointXYZRGBEE11applyFilterERSt6vectorIiSaIiEE[_ZN3pcl25StatisticalOutlierRemovalINS_11PointXYZRGBEE11applyFilterERSt6vectorIiSaIiEE]+0x1): undefined reference to `pcl::StatisticalOutlierRemoval<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::applyFilterIndices(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&)'
CMakeFiles/tests/11_pcl/removeOutliers.dir/removeOutliers.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTVN3pcl25StatisticalOutlierRemovalINS_11PointXYZRGBEEE[_ZTVN3pcl25StatisticalOutlierRemovalINS_11PointXYZRGBEEE]+0x48): undefined reference to `pcl::StatisticalOutlierRemoval<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::applyFilter(pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>&)'
```

In my CMakeList I have the following lines :

```
find_package(PCL 1.3 REQUIRED COMPONENTS common io visualization)
include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})
```

and :

```
add_executable(tests/11_pcl/removeOutliers removeOutliers.cpp)
target_link_libraries(tests/11_pcl/removeOutliers ${PCL_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

In my cpp file I only tried to initialize the outlier removal with :

```
pcl::StatisticalOutlierRemoval<pcl::PointXYZRGB> sor;
```

And I have the following headers :

```
#include <pcl/common/common_headers.h>
#include <pcl/features/normal_3d.h>
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <pcl/visualization/pcl_visualizer.h>
#include <pcl/console/parse.h>

//Filters
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl/filters/statistical_outlier_removal.h>
```

I guess I might have a missing component in PCL... Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I have found the solution. I was actually missing a component in PCL (filters)..

```
find_package(PCL 1.3 REQUIRED COMPONENTS common io visualization filters)
```

And everything works fine now.